# Particle in a potential well in mathematica

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, hamiltonian

For a three qubit-chain in a connected state barrier tunneling captured in the Hamiltonian below with J=1, U=3.

[image]

How do I fin J' when sites 1 and 3 decouple from each other?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/589193/pertubation-theory

Comment: Where is there a potential well? Why is *Mathematica* in the title?